# i cant make my 8GB flash drive bootable?

Tags: boot

i can't Boot from a usb i always end up in WindowsXP start screen i don't know what's the problem am using Windows XP sp2 (dont know if that's the problem)

Comment: Please edit your question and include how you've tried to make the live USB. Also, you might consider checking the boot order in your BIOS and that USB booting is enabled/possible.

Comment: well i used Yumi and LiLi currently trying UNetBootin and in the bios thingy i make the 1st boot is USB-HDD 2nd and 3rd too

Currently UnetBootin is not working or it's just taking too long

(sorry am a begginer)

Comment: @omarlink Unetbootin takes some time as it must download the Ubuntu ISO. Please allow it to finish,

Comment: @hexafraction in the installing process it says Downloading files (Done)

Comment: UNetbootin is currently Stuck on 5%.. ah nevermind working now :)

Comment: You might want to consider using `dd` under Cygwin, right now I don't have Windows installed so I can not be of much help if you decide to use `dd` under Windows/Cygwin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you downloaded the .iso image and installing it in the USB using Unetbooting, then you should modify the booting priority (do that on the BIOS, at the start up of the computer) making the USB Device (removable media) to boot as the first order/priority, leaving the HDD at the second place. Then Save and Exit Bios. Booting sequence will take the USB at first.